# WildFly error while adding user

Tags: cmd, jboss, wildfly, user-permissions

I am trying to add a Management User using the add-user.bat.  My JAVA-HOME is set to the current JDK. The error I'm getting is this:

[image: Command Prompt error WFLYDM0030]

Keep in mind, I'm not the most Tech savvy person ever, so even simple suggestions might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix an "Access is Denied" error you should be able to either:

A) Run the command prompt as administrator, then do those steps again, or

B) Edit the file permissions of `mgmt-users.properties` in the standalone
   configuration folder, so that your user (or everyone) can edit the file.